# How to effectively frame a sentence describing one's project in a resume?

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to write a brief 2-3 line description of my hobby project in my resume, and have written the following:

> **Steganography and Image Compression** (Hobby project)    May 2006 - Jul 2006
>   This project implements hiding a computer data file in a bitmap image or wave audio, and also retrieves the hidden data file. It also implements compression of a bitmap image using a combination of quantization and run length encoding algorithms.

Somehow I find the "This project implements" rather strange. It also uses "also" twice, which although referring once each to each half of the project, still feels a bit odd. I am not sure if writing a resume in first person ("In this project, I did ..."), and I have read that this is generally discouraged.

Moreover, the "this project" seems redundant, because it is quite clear from the context that it is a project description, but I cannot figure out how to rewrite the above sentences without specifically using the word "project". How should I phrase these in a more "effective" way?

Comment: How about this? *Steganography and Image Compression (Hobby project) May 2006 - Jul 2006 -- An implementation of ...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as making your sentences flow a little more naturally goes, I would try something like:

> The **purpose of this project(/program/system)** is to hide a computer data file in a bitmap image or wave audio, **and to retrieve** the hidden data file. The (project/program/system) **also compresses** a bitmap image using a combination of quantization and run length encoding algorithms.

The only bit of strangeness in your original text is indeed "the project implements", like you mentioned. The *project* isn't doing the implementing - the humans are. I updated the text to remove some of that ambiguity, and get rid of one of your "also"s.

As far as writing a resume in the first person goes, opinions can vary wildly. There's a Stack Exchange site for just this type of question, including an extensive [resumes tag](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume).